# Specified cast is not valid. From Cloud Code result in Xamarin

Tags: parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.ios, parse-cloud-code

I'm getting a "Specified cast is not valid." error message when trying to get back a list of dictionaries from Cloud Code in Xamarin.

Below are the calls I've tried.

I appreciate the time and feedback on how I can get this work and return a list of dictionaries.

```
var searchResults = await Parse.ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>("searchAlbums", new
Dictionary<string, object> {
                    {"firstName", firstName},
                    {"lastName", lastName},
                });

var searchResults = await Parse.ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>>>("searchAlbums", new
Dictionary<string, object> {
                    {"firstName", firstName},
                    {"lastName", lastName},
                });

var searchResults = await Parse.ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>>("searchAlbums", new
Dictionary<string, object> {
                    {"firstName", firstName},
                    {"lastName", lastName},
                });

var searchResults = await Parse.ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>("searchAlbums", new
Dictionary<string, object> {
                    {"firstName", firstName},
                    {"lastName", lastName},
                });
```

Comment: What is the type expected type to be returned from the call? ie what is the type for `searchResults`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```cs
IDictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object> 
    {
        {"firstName", firstName},
        {"lastName", lastName},
    };

var searchResults = await Parse.ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<object>("searchAlbums", dict);
```

From there you should see what is being return and then you could use a more concrete type for the expected result.

Comment: Just tried that code and added Console.WriteLine(searchResults.GetType()); and it returns: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]

Comment: ok while debugging put a break point and look at what the objects in the list look like. that should give you an idea of what you need to case it to. so far you've confirmed that it is a list of something. :)